# The default gateway in routing table recovers after been deleted for a while

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, gateway

After I deleted the default gateway entry of routing table in my Ubuntu host, browser can not reach the ip address of Yahoo. And I run a script to keep printing the entries of routing table with loop. After a while, the default gateway deleted before comes back and browser refresh out the Yahoo Search page. It seems the Default Gateway sends some info to the host and I have no idea why this happened? Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening g is that you are getting the IP address from your router via a DHCP lease. There is a process running to periodically renew your DHCP connection - and when this runs it replaces your default route.

The easiest way to fix this is to change your computer to use a static IP address instead.